# Tibco Spotfire - Passing Global value to Information Link

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I have large number of info links(50+) which loads data from different table for last 30 days as mentioned below.(EVENT_TIME column is common for all the info links)

> WHERE A1.`EVENT_TIME` >= Date_Add(curdate(),interval -30 day)

But I may need to change the current number of days from 30 to something else in future.

And I am looking at an easy solution (like a global variable) to have this implemented such that I will input the value in one single place and map that to all other info links.

I have looked at personalized and parameterised infolinks but not sure how to achieve this.

Any suggestions are most welcome!
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use parameterized info links, I think you'll still need to enter the #days in PER info link -- or at least load the analysis, choose a value, then load the info links.

how frequently is this going to change? if it's not frequent, you could `CREATE TABLE settings (name VARCHAR(255), value VARCHAR(255)); INSERT INTO settings VALUES('num_days', '30');` and then in your info links do `...WHERE A1.EVENT_TIME >= Date_Add(curdate(),interval (SELECT value FROM settings WHERE setting='num_days') day)`

you'll need to rewrite that SQL to valid syntax for whatever DB you're using, but that should work.

Comment: Excellent!.Actually i did everything on your answer upto before the sub-query part. There i thought I have to bring them as columns and that's where spotfire threw an error that two tables cannot be joined. I didn't know that I can actually run queries without bringing them as columns into the infolink! Thanks once again! :)